# Mapping existing database with code first approch

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have implemented asp .net application without Code first approach. now i want to build different system with existing database and code first.

```
 public class EmployeeEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ResourceCode { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public int Gender { get; set; }

        public int Status { get; set; }

        public string NIC { get; set; }
}
```

now i want to add code first entities.

```
 [Table("ExternalApplicantEntity")]
    public class ExternalApplicantEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("EmployeeEntity")]
        //public int Created_By { get; set; }
        //public virtual EmployeeEntity EmployeeEntity { get; set; }

        public string NIC { get; set; }

        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        public string Institute { get; set; }
```

how i combine these codes?

Comment: If you already have db then how it can be code first?

Comment: Previous codes does not follow Code first approach. now i want to follow it with existing system.

Comment: According to Microsoft, it's doable.  Have a look at [Code First to an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database)